# Choices for html5 drag and drop web dev tool are?

Tags: html

I'm researching the choice of drag and drop html5 web development tools that can be used to quick prototype, test, and possibly deploy a fully interactive animated website.

I've taken a look at Google Web Developer but that looks like it is intended to develop animated ads and not web sites.

So I thought it would be interesting and educational to ask you guys to help create a practical list of the 'all-in-one' tool choices that are out there and are the most useful.

Of course writing code is the best choice when time and budget allow but for a quick 'live' demo or prototype drag and drop can often be used to illustrate an idea quickly and maybe inspire more budget for the project :-)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you spare some $$, try [Macaw](http://macaw.co/)... there's also a trial version if you want to do something in 15 days. :-) -- edit: 30 days

Comment: I took a look at MaCaw but...
- Forum - No (public) user forum on their site or anywhere I could find and that is troubling.
- Animation - No mention of being able to use Macaw with html5 to create animation... or maybe I missed it
Questions:
a - is there a Macaw forum?
b - Is it a tool for creating web animation?
c - Any idea on the size of the userbase so far? 
.. small userbase means hard times for the developers...
.. large userbase indicates that the product stands a good chance of surviving and thriving)

Comment: gtramontina, How can I expand the view of your response so I can mark your answer as helpful. I do not see a check mark and can not find where to click to have your answer appear as a normally posted response. thanks for any help.

Comment: Macaw is a very new tool, and you're right, its focus is not on animation, but design. As far as user base, I don't know, but there has been lots of buzz around it. When it comes to animation (your main concern), you might get around with Google Web Developer, as you mentioned... And, if you're willing to experiment with something even newer, there's a project on [github called theatrejs](https://github.com/AriaMinaei/theatrejs). I'll post a summary of this conversation as the answer. Cheers -g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you spare some $$, try [Macaw](http://macaw.co/)... there's also a trial version if you want to do something in 30 days.

Macaw is a very new tool with focus on web design. As far as user base, I can't tell, but there has been lots of buzz around it.

You might get around with Google Web Developer for animation, as you mentioned... But if you're willing to experiment with something even newer, there's a [project on github called theatrejs](https://github.com/AriaMinaei/theatrejs).

Comment: Thanks gtramontina. I'll check out theatrejs on github.